# removing integers from an array

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

I need to make an array for the co ordinates of my sprites and i wanted to remove the co-ordinate once the sprite has that co-ordinate from the array as i don't want another sprite having the same co-ordinate, i can't seem to get it to work, there are no errors and when debugging it says nsexception and quits. what am i doing wrong and where do i deallocate the arrays? when i release them in dealloc it says i need to declare them.

```
CGPoint cg1 = CGPointMake(33,33);
NSValue *cg1obj = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:cg1];

CGPoint cg2 = CGPointMake(33,97);
NSValue *cg2obj = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:cg2];

NSMutableArray *numberxy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; int pointcount = 0;
[numberxy insertObject:cg1obj atIndex:pointcount++];
[numberxy insertObject:cg2obj atIndex:pointcount++];

NSMutableArray  *sprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; int spritecount = 0;
[sprites insertObject:red1 atIndex:spritecount++];
[sprites insertObject:red2 atIndex:spritecount++];

for (int i=0; i<3;i++) {
    int rpoint = arc4random() % 3;
    int rsprite = arc4random() % 3;

    CGPoint point = [[numberxy objectAtIndex:rpoint] CGPointValue];

    CCSprite *sprite1 = [sprites objectAtIndex:rsprite];

    sprite1.position = ccp(point.x,point.y);

    if (sprite1.position.x == point.x && sprite1.position.y == point.y) {
        [numberxy removeObjectAtIndex:rpoint];
        [sprites removeObjectAtIndex:rsprite];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is weird. Why is `xValue` defined after it is used? You may have a leak if `xValue` was defined previously in the same manner and now you are redefining `xValue`. You then check if `X` is in the new `xValue`. There is nothing in the new `xValue` so the `if` statement will evaluate to false, so nothing will be removed.

```
NSNumber *X = [NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumberx];
[xValue containsObject: numberx];

xValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if ([xValue containsObject:X]) {
    [numberx removeObject:X];
}
```

Also what is the point of `[xValue containsObject: numberx];` outside of the if statement? It doesn't have a purpose.

Comment: Not weird -- nonsense.  Dangermouse's code doesn't make any sense and indicates a lack of understanding of pointers -- of object references.  My suggestion would be to read the Objective-C guide and then play computer on that code;  explain what every line of code does.

Comment: @David - sorry about that i ended up copying code from two different programs into one as i had two projects open at the time, i'll edit the code

Comment: @David, it keeps giving me an nsexception on the debugger console and crashes should i post the whole code?

Comment: @Dangermouse. No don't post everything here. Removing integers from an array is trivial. You are probably having issues with something else. You need to break your code into pieces and debug it.

Comment: @David. i found while debugging that i get this error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0' don't really know what it means?

Comment: @Dangermouse, it means that the object that you're inserting into the array has not been created/allocated.

Comment: @David, my points have been created i think the problem is with the sprites although i have declared them in the header file do i have to convert them into objects or something?

Comment: @Dangermouse, yes, you have to make sure that anything that you're putting into the array is an object. In your case cg1obj, cg2obj, red1 and red2 must all be objects.

Comment: @David, how do you make sprites into an object?

Comment: @Dangermouse, I don't know. I've never worked with cocos2d before. You should ask that as a separate question.